# Arduino libraries development and Eclipse Soleber

Tags: arduino-ide, ide, eclipse

I have a project on Arduino IDE. A .ino sketch with some extra .h/.cpp files and 2-3 libraries that I keep in ~/Arduino/libraries.

In addition to the IDE I do open the libraries as generic project in eclipse, of course this means no symbols resolution and no indexing which is bad for me.
So I wanted to give Solebera try. I can see that Soleber includes the directory above however when compiling, I can clearly see it doesn't include any of those libraries! Also trying to add them doesn't work as the preference screen doesn't allow it/lists it.

So you help please,

1. how can i make it even compile?
2. will eclipse index it? I mean if I press 'ctrl + shift + r' and start typing RH_RF95 (radiohead rf95 driver cpp file) will it let me open it? (it does for Platformio).

Comment: in Eclipse Arduino Preferences you can set if it adds the libraries automatically. If you choose not auto, then use "Add a library to selected project" in Arduino menu. 2) yes

Comment: I edit and debug libraries in a test project for the library. So the developed library is one of the libraries used by the project.

Comment: nop didn't work for me, "automatic is set for me but adding RHGeenricDriver.h doesn't cause the library to be added. adding "libraries" to the project adds ALL the libraries , i can see them in the makefile but they are excluded including radiohead which has an include in the main file. so it doesn't work. seems like it's not the way to go after all.

Comment: do you have the libraries folder configured in Preferences?

Comment: Yes i do.  Its configured correctly,  i checked.

Comment: try with a new project

Comment: It is a new project,  i ipened it just for the tseting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90308/discussion-between-juraj-and-codescriber).